# Blazor webassembly access-control-allow-origin error and Google API

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, cors, google-api-dotnet-client, blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor WebAssembly proj:

[image]

In my Google console I created a new Web application project where I specified
*Authorized Javascript Origin* and *Authorized redirect URIs*, like below

[image: 2]

In my Blazor proj I added these packages:
Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3
Google.Apis.Drive.v3

My startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            ***services
                .AddAuthentication(o =>
                {
                    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "{--myclientid--}";
                    options.ClientSecret = {"--myclientsecret--}";
                });***
        }
```

and also

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
          
            app.UseRouting();

            ***app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();***


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

I my WeatherforcastController i added this method:

```
  [HttpGet("DriveFileList")]
        [GoogleScopedAuthorize(DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveReadonly)]
        public async Task<List<String>> DriveFileList([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
        {
            GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = cred
            });
            var files = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
            var fileNames = files.Files.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            return fileNames;
        }
```

I call above method from my FetchData.razor page like below:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{    
     List<String> myFiles = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<String>>("WeatherForecast/DriveFileList");   
}
```

I run and get a CORS error:
[image: 3]

Is there a workaround? Are there other approaches to access the Google Api from Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: Do you intend to do this with client side or server side Blazor?

Comment: Thanx. I was hoping this could be done client side, would that be possible?

Comment: Yes but i bet you would need to use the Google.apis.js client library and not the Google .net client library.   I did this back when blazor just came out worked like a charm but im not sure i have any sample code floating around.

Comment: Thank you, i will investigate the "Google.apis.js" way forward

Comment: I did a bit more digging for you.   [#1427](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1427) Blazor is not supported in any format with the Google .net client library and the team has decided its not a priority.   [#1830](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1830)

Comment: Thanx again, I tried "Google.apis.js" which worked, however it became slow, not sure why, I might  try ASP.NET MVC and see how this works out...

Comment: I am wondering if i cant build an extension to the library for Blazor since the team doesn't want to do it.   Main issue i found was that importing the package actually bakes the webassembly project completely by removing / upgrading / some of the needed packages

Comment: I would appreciate all efforts getting the google api working with blazor

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the API i think its an issue with the authorization.

Comment: Yes, i believe the CORS error appears when the user is redirected to Google for authorization

Comment: I cant even get as far as you did which class library did you include?

Comment: Only these i think: Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 
Google.Apis.Drive.v3 Where do u get stuck?

Comment: Can you try to change "localhost" to 0.0.0.0 in the URI?

Comment: Sorry i gave up and scrapped the project, let me know if you succeed